# gitlab ci shell runner reports profile loading problem

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to setup the gitlab ci shell runner. I've used the docker runner before successfully but now I'd like to use another docker container within my testing routine and therefore switched to the shell runner.
After registering I'm running into an exception:

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: exit status 1. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

So, I went through the linked material but that didn't cure the problem. Now, I verified that the gitlab-runner user exists and it has access to docker (needed to run the docker test container). Also the gitlab-runner user is part of the docker group. I can also `--login`, fire up the `/bin/bash` without problems.

Still, all I get from the runner side is the the enigmatic message above. What other checkups to I need to do to track down this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The careful reader will find the answer:

> "A common failure is when you have a .bash_logout that tries to clear
> the console."